# Is it possible to produce border with a single image

Tags: html, css

Can I produce something like this with a single image using css and html:

[image: Bordered Page]

This is the single image

[image: Single Image]

I have tried using border-image but it did not work out as expected. This is what I got with border-image:

[image: Result]

My Code:

```
border: 40px solid transparent;
    border-image-source: url(../images/mlt-border.png);
    border-image-repeat: round;
    border-image-slice: 10;
```

But I need the image to be repeated as in the first picture.

Comment: `border-image` appears to be the solution. You said you had tried it. Show a [mcve]. Explain what the difference between what you got and what you expected was.

Comment: This is a btter reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with one image, but that image needs to be divided into 9 sections, where the corners of the image correspond to the corners of the border, and similarly the edges of the image correspond to the edges of the border. In this case, you just need a 3x3 grid of the same image, like so:

[image: Border image]

Then you need to use the border-slice property to specify which parts of the image should be used for which parts of the border. The 47's and 40's correspond to the fact that each of the 9 cells of the image is 40px wide by 47px high.

```css
.border {
    width: 200px;
    height: 235px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 47px;
    border-right-width: 40px;
    border-bottom-width: 47px;
    border-left-width: 40px;
    border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGyqa.png") round;
    border-image-width: 47px 40px;
    border-image-slice: 47 40 47 40; /* measuring in px from top, right, bottom and left edges of the image respectively */


}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

A full explanation of the border-image syntax can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are two samples, round and stretch:

```css
#borderimg-round {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% round;
}
#borderimg-stretch {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% stretch;
  -o-border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% stretch;
  border-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/deltreetech/image/upload/v1565010696/mlt-border_ekrg5s.png) 20% stretch;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="borderimg-round">border-image: url(image.png) 20% round;</p>
  <p id="borderimg-stretch">border-image: url(image.png) 20% stretch;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have problems, post here more details!